# JSON Modelling Approaches

Tags: json, modeling

Imagine I am storing a person's phone numbers in JSON format. One such JSON record might look as follows:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "phoneNumber": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ]
}
```

One alternative structure to the above is:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "homePhone": {
    "number": "212 555-1234"
  },
  "mobilePhone": {
    "number": "646 555-4567"
  }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of the two modelling approaches? The obvious one I see is that the first approach allows one to retrieve **all** phones in one go.

Comment: A third approach that blends the first and second examples above is: `{ …, "phoneNumber": { "home": "…", "mobile": "…" } }` This allows you to retrieve all the phone numbers at once and to access each by name through path notation (ex. `phoneNumber.home`) instead of having to iterate over an array parsing `type` values. Though the array does have benefits for storing larger collections where easy iteration is desired for filtering. I think it comes down to a balance of needs and preference.

Comment: Great, thanks @gfullam. I will only have a fixed number of "types" so your approach will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to decide what to do in this cases you should think in your implementation too.

Let's say for example that you will be parsing and using this with Python. If you put it as a list, you will have to loop through the list in order to find a given number which in the worst case scenario might end up as an O(n) task.

If you re-factor it to be a dictionary (hash table), looking up a phone number by accessing the right key would be closer to O(1).

In summary, what you're doing with your data and how are you going to use it should dictate its structure.

Comment: Good point, your reminder to think about my implementation, thanks @zom-pro.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first exemple is better.

With your first solution phone number is just a collection, and it's easy to add/delete/filters phone number.

```
// ES6    
const allMobilePhones = user.phones.filter(phone => phone.type === 'mobile');

// With Lodash/Underscore
var allMobilePhones = _(user.phones).filter(function(phone){
   return phone === 'mobile';
});
```

It's also more readable for documentation, you don't have to say look at attributes `mobilePhone`, `homePhone`, `unusedPhone`, `workPhone`. Another thing, if you add new type of phone, you don't care you just have to add new `type` value.

If you are working to expose your JSON over an API, take a look at:
[micro-api](http://micro-api.org) or [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand your line of code where you are defining the allMobilePhones constant, specifically the bit `(phone => phone.type === 'mobile')`.

Comment: Sorry It's [ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features). You can do something like with underscore/lodash: `_.filter(data.phones), function(phone){ return phone.type === 'mobile; })`